# MS Excel 2013: changing markers in scatter graphs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Is it possible to use the numeric value of individual data points as the marker in a scatter plot (instead of the standard dot/square/triangle markers)?  It would look like a trendline connecting a series of numbers.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color and transparency of the marker. The following steps should be done:

Step 1: Click on the data label (the numbers part). Click on CHART TOOLS > FORMAT. Then on the Label Options on the right column menu, select Label Position as "Above." This step helps you separates the numbers and the markers.

Step 2: Once the numbers are now above the markers, click on one of the markers to select them all. Once selected, at the Format Data Series menu on the right, select Series Options > Fill & Line (the bucket icon).

- First select the Solid Line.
- Move on to the next Market option, change the Color to white and Transparency to 100%.

The result should then be a solid line and the numeric values will be above the line.